# how to use both condition() and addcondition() for a same search model

Tags: php, yii

I have a grid view with a condition "upload_date = today", but when I search for other dates it is not filtering the grid. Here is my model:

```
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.
    $date=date('Y-m-d');
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria(array('order'=>'upload_date ASC'));
    $criteria->condition = "upload_date='$date' ";
     if(isset($_GET['upload_date']))
           {
           $criteria->addCondition('upload_date = :upload_date','AND'); 
          $criteria->params[':upload_date'] = $this->upload_date;
             }

    $criteria->compare('book_id',$this->book_id);
    $criteria->compare('date_received',$this->date_received,true);
    $criteria->compare('batch',$this->batch,true);
    $criteria->compare('isbn_no',$this->isbn_no,true);
    $criteria->compare('book_title',$this->book_title,true);
    $criteria->compare('auther_name',$this->auther_name,true);
    $criteria->compare('upload_date',$this->upload_date,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>50
        ),

    ));
}
```

I am trying to use both condition and addcondition in same search. What did I do wrong in the model above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function search()
{
 $criteria=new CDbCriteria(array('order'=>'upload_date ASC'));

 if(isset($_GET['ModelName']['upload_date']))
 {
  $criteria->compare('upload_date',$this->upload_date,true);
  // $criteria->addCondition('upload_date = :upload_date');
  // $criteria->params[':upload_date'] = $this->upload_date;
 }
 else 
 {
  $date=date('Y-m-d');
  $criteria->condition = "upload_date='$date' "; 
 }
  $criteria->compare('book_id',$this->book_id);
  $criteria->compare('date_received',$this->date_received,true);
  $criteria->compare('batch',$this->batch,true);
  $criteria->compare('isbn_no',$this->isbn_no,true);
  $criteria->compare('book_title',$this->book_title,true);
  $criteria->compare('auther_name',$this->auther_name,true);
  $criteria->compare('upload_date',$this->upload_date,true);

  return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
     'criteria'=>$criteria,
     'pagination'=>array(
     'pageSize'=>50
     ), 

 ));
}
```

You don't need addCondition, specially because you are adding a condition to the same column.

**Edit**:
In your main initial condition you have already set `upload_date = $date`, now if you add condition to it, say `$_GET['ModelName']['upload_date']` provided by the user in the filter, your actual db query will become something like `select * from tbl_name where upload_date = 'xxx' and upload_date = 'yyy'` , here xxx=$date you gave, and yyy=date provided by user. Now if xxx != yyy, how will the query return any value? It is not possible.

Hope you got this explanation.

Comment: let me know if you need more clarifications

Comment: thanks dude i got answer by this....i have another question is there anyway to use daterange between condition for timestamp using date picker

Comment: help in this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578629/yii-model-search-with-daterange-for-time-stamp]