# How to generate a Yii Report

Tags: yii, yii-events

I'm new at Yii, and I'm trying to generate some reports with some user input (fill the form and then click 'generate').  I want to query my database to look for some transactions on a date range, but I really don't know how to do it.

Does anyone have any examples I might look at?

Thanks in advance.  I would really appreciate the help.  Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In Yii, you can create a table and using the Gii crud generator to create a form and view. This view could be considered a report.

what kind of report do you want exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer lets suppose I create a form where I have to put a date range for some report, lets say the amount of transactions i've done on this date range. something like that i dont know if i was clear enough?

Comment: in the view you would add 2 controls to choose the date. Then in the controller, you would use the date's to filter your data.

Comment: Mmmm ok is something like the default search that the CRUD generator gives you, but I want to get the results after I click the button, before this i dont want that anything is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Commonly reports are taken by existing created transaction only.there is no need to create any input fields to reports.As by the answer of **'jarchuleta'** you can create forms using crud and For date range report you can [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578629/yii-model-search-with-daterange-for-time-stamp), question may be irrelevant but the code i posted is for date range report

Comment: Thanks but, how do I generate after I put the date range? how do I handle the "generate button"?

Comment: for my projects to generate the reports by existing gridview using checkbox to with select all rows and give the all selected PK of data to controllers by using a button.and using sql method  you can fill the report table.sorry for my late reply and bad English..if you have any doubt you can ask.